# How to create a UI that uses a Scanner to print a set of lines

Tags: java, user-interface, java.util.scanner

Hello I'm just staring out on java, and I've been looking everywhere how to make a UI that based on a Scanner would print the the following methods of parsing on separate window:

```
Character [A] located at position 0 is a vowel
Character [b] located at position 1 is a consonant
Character [r] located at position 2 is a consonant
Character [a] located at position 3 is a vowel
Character [h] located at position 4 is a consonant
...
             16 [Abraham Lincoln ]
              14 [braham Lincoln]
               12 [raham Lincol]
                10 [aham Linco]
                 8 [ham Linc]
                  6 [am Lin]
                   4 [m Li]
                    2 [ L]
                     0 []
```

I have the code for the methods that do that, but for now all I have is a Scanner that would transform any input I type on Eclipse's console into a string that is then parsed.

```
    String enterName;
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    enterName = name.nextLine();
```

Any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Scanner` for text input as you have presented above is the norm for console based applications.

If you wish create a *Graphical* User interface you can use [Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.htm) and use a `JTextField` to accept user input. `Scanner` is not needed in this case.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see what I can do about it

Answer (score 0):

Create a `JFrame`, add a `JPanel` inside it with a layout manager like `BorderLayout`. Inside the panel add a `JTextArea` or a `JEditorPane` in which you would be able to add the text that is read using the `Scanner`.